# How to fix css to show show side nav items

Tags: html, css

I have one big problem.. I want working css to have for my menu where label and id are always the same the problems starts when i want populate categories from database on website with my code i must write css for all categories which can not work with my website.

I need to edit css to always be the same working for any nav menu item so label and id can be the same just title and urls are different

Thanks

```
<style>
    #ls{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    #ls:checked + ul {
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<label for="ls" class="list-group-item cat">cars <span class="badge badge-secondary idstatmargin"><?php echo $data[6]+$data[7]+$data[8]+$data[9];?></span></label>
    <input id="ls" type="checkbox" style="display:none;" />
    <ul class="subcat">
        <li class="list-group-item"><a class="navcolor" href="<?php echo URLROOT;?>/market/products/6">Cars</a> <span class="badge badge-secondary float-right"><?php echo $data[6];?></span></li>
    </ul>
```

Can you please make this style css to work with one id. always the same. because when i want two dropdown navigation menus I must make new css with different label for and input id which is here "ls"

I bet there is some fix so I can use only one css for all inputs... please help me i need to display categories on my Marketplace Custom website. I will send for bear for solution

Answer (score 0):

Use classes.

```css
.red {background: red;}
.blue {background: blue;}
```

```html
<input class="red" size="10"></input>
<input class="red" size="10"></input>
<input class="blue" size="10"></input>
<input class="blue" size="10"></input>
```